# Ubuntu Mate 20.04 graphics drivers

Tags: 20.04, hp, ubuntu-mate

My laptop is HP IDS UMA Ryzen 3 2200U 255 G7 with graphics card AMD Radeon Graphics 60570-A (Vesa 3). I have installed Ubuntu Mate 20.04 LTS and it displays:

[image]

I have searched the internet but I cannot find solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you can navigate to them, changing resolution in Displays to one your monitor can do at a stable 60 hertz or switching the window manager to Marco (no composition) in Mate Tweak are my work-arounds.

Keep in mind my APU is a A12 on a budget Lenovo laptop so YMMV.